# Change audio level selection border to something besides orange

Tags: 18.04, gnome

Where can I find the CSS to change the orange audio border around my audio level selection in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome gtk 3 Adwaita Dark theme
(not sure if pertains to the theme or not)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

look for this part from the shell theme you are using

```
/* Slider */
.slider {
  height: 1em;
  -slider-height: 0.3em;
  -slider-background-color: #363633;
  -slider-border-color: #1f1f1c;
  -slider-active-background-color: blue;
  -slider-active-border-color: yellow;
  -slider-border-width: 1px;
  -slider-handle-radius: 6px; }
```

`-slider-active-border-color: yellow` I have choose the color yellow

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much PRATAP

Comment: Hi, Please accept the answer as solved by ticking the right mark on the left side of the answer.. Thank You..